# How to write Excel formula in cells in python

Tags: python, excel, formula, cell

I try to add Excel formula in some columns within a loop. 
To make it short : I have an excel spreadsheet in which I generate successfully random amount in the 2 first colums (A and B) for 3000 lines thanks to a loop.
Now I would like to write in column C the formula which multiply A with B and in the column D the addition of A + C within the same loop. 
Thank you very much for your help in advance !

```
import xlsxwriter
import os
import random


path = r"/Users/MAC/Desktop/test.xlsx"
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(path)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("formula")
worksheet.write(0, 0, "Amount")
worksheet.write(0, 1, "Interest")
worksheet.write(0, 2, "Fees")
worksheet.write(0, 3, "Total Amount")

for n in range(1, 3000):
    worksheet.write(n, 0, random.randint(1,150000))
    worksheet.write(n, 1, random.randint(1, 100))
    # worksheet.write(n,2, a*b/100) ??????
    # worksheet.write(n,3, a+c) ??????
workbook.close()
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Which part are you struggling with? Have you done any research?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [worksheet.write_formula](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#write_formula).
Example:

```
for n in range(1, 10):
    worksheet.write(n, 0, random.randint(1,150000))
    worksheet.write(n, 1, random.randint(1, 100))
    cell1 = xl_rowcol_to_cell(n,0)
    cell2 = xl_rowcol_to_cell(n,1)
    worksheet.write_formula(n, 2, f'=({cell1}*{cell2})/100')
workbook.close()
```

where [xl_rowcol_to_cell](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_notation.html) converts a cell from coordinates to string.